# Compiling Curl and GTK

Tags: c++, curl, g++

When I compile the following code

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

void pop_class()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl) 
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast id=2158867&appid=a4f247bfd153738d2cd1757224361972");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("glade/window_main.glade");

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    pop_class();

    return 0;
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

with the following command,

```
g++ -c -g -O0 -Wall -pthread -pipe src/main.cpp -lcurl `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -o main.o
```

I get this warning:

```
src/main.cpp: In function ‘void pop_class()’:
src/main.cpp:15:11: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   15 |  CURLcode res;
```

Then on compiling the object file with

```
g++ -o temp_app main.o -pthread `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `pop_class()':
/home/carl/project/template/src/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/carl/project/template/src/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/carl/project/template/src/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/carl/project/template/src/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/carl/project/template/src/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/carl/project/template/src/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why all your errors seem to be related to curl, is because you forgot to tell the compiler to link to it in your second command.

In other words:

```
g++ -o temp_app main.o -pthread `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic
```

should become

```
g++ -o temp_app main.o -pthread -lcurl `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic
```

Comment: It's a different question in which you should post your glade file, but probably you have an XML entry which describes a signal with the given name as callback. Either you remove that entry or you properly define that callback in your code